# Can We use Office 365 API's to manipulate word documents , convert into pdf etc

Tags: ms-word, automation, pdf-generation, office365, office365api

Can We use Office 365 API's to manipulate word documents/ convert into pdf etc..., instead of using Word Automation libraries or Interop Libraries? What are the licensing terms to it, can we use it on a server.

Answer (score 2):

There are no native methods exposed in either the current Office 365 API, or in the present state of the Office 365 Unified API, that would accomplish explicit document conversions. Performing the actual document conversion elsewhere and re-uploading it via the Office 365 API would be the nearest you could come at present.

If you're trying to leverage or extend the power of Word, you should check out [Apps for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220060(v=office.15).aspx). If you want to use data that an organization stores with Office 365, e.g. if you want to get all the documents belonging to a user X for example, then you should use [Office 365 APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15)).

You could also consider licensing a pre-built App such as [Tru Copy/Paste](https://store.office.com/tru-copy-and-paste-WA104362813.aspx?assetid=WA104362813) or [Muhimbi](https://store.office.com/muhimbi-pdf-converter-for-sharepoint-online-WA104379298.aspx?assetid=WA104379298&sourcecorrid=2505c10e-50f7-4121-b2ab-5b969a663966&searchapppos=0), as a means to avoid having to develop a web service/conversion application from scratch.

Comment: So if I cannot use Office 365 API and I don't want to use Apps for Office. What other options do I have, I need to to manipulate a document and generate a PDF version of the same, Do I have to go the traditional way by using office Assemblies in .Net, but can i use them on the server.

Comment: Yes, my first choice would be to use a PDF conversion library such as  (already mentioned) Word Automation, http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/ , http://www.aspose.com or http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ .

Plug the converter into into a web service, and host it on a local or cloud-hosted (such as an Azure) server.

Answer (score -1):

Look into the .NET "word.application" COM object.  It does everything you want to do.  If you only want to dip your toe in then explore it with PowerShell via this command string: $word = new-object -com word.application

Comment: That would work only within a UI application, where there is an active logged on user session.  For server apps, this must not be used, or bad things will happen.